# Install Zip module in PHP8.2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, php, zip

I am trying to install the zip module in PHP 8.2, in Amazon Linux 2023.  However, either the module is not available or it is a different name than the previous ones.

I have tried.

- sudo yum install php-zip
- sudo yum install php8.2-zip
- sudo yum install php-pecl-zip

Everything I have tried so far responds with "No match for argument..."

When I run the command **PHP -m**, zip does not show in the list of PHP Modules.

Is there another way I can find the module? If I need to connect to another repo I'll do that.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: "Find and install software packages on an Amazon Linux instance": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/find-install-software.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find the package using the [RPM finder](https://rpmfind.net/).

Here's the list of RPMs that contains the zip module for PHP 8.2:
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php82-php-zip

Comment: Amazon Linux uses yum, but it has long diverged from CentOS/RHEL. Its list is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages.html.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux [doesn't appear to have a package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages.html) for PHP's zip extension.

You can install it [via PECL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php):

```
sudo pecl install zip
```

Per https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/320 you may need to install `php8.2-devel libzip libzip-devel` via yum first.